# How to allow guest access in Cognito

Tags: aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito

We are looking to move to Cognito for user authentication. Currently we rely on our system to create the user and authenticate using JWT tokens generated internally. We also have a guest user role where anonymous users are given access to limited apis. To achieve this, we first create the guest user as a normal user in our system and mark it a guest in db. This way we can generate JWT tokens for guest users that can be used to authorize limited set of apis.

With Cognito, creating authenticated users is straightforward as userpool token (ID token) generated can be used in Api Gateway with Cognito authorizer. However, we are looking to implement guest user access as well via Cognito. Userpools does not have that support. The only option seems available is Cognito Identity pool for unauthenticated access. But this requires IAM credentials to be generated and passed to Api Gateway which is different than ID Token flow for authenticated users. Also, it does not mention how we can attach custom information to the identity (guest) so that it can be decoded at the authorizer level in Api Gateway and passed to backend service.

Is Identity pool the only approach to implement guest access? My usecase does not require access to any AWS resources except Api Gateway for guest users. Please note the Api Gateway apis used for guest users are also being used for authenticated users.